# ActionBar's action items not working on some devices

Tags: android, spinner, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-spinner

I'm developing an app using `ActionbarSherlock` for backwards compatibility, and I'm currently having problems with the `Spinner` I add to the `ActionBar`.

Scenario:

I'm using `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` and each tab is a `Fragment` with it's own inflated menu.

I have no problem inflating and populating the menus or `Spinner`s, but the problem is that the `Spinner` is not expanding when a user clicks it. However, when the user slides to another `fragment` the `Spinner` expands (and is shown in the wrong `fragment`), and when sliding back again the `Spinner` works as expected in the correct `fragment`.

This problem only occurs on devices <4.0.x (haven't tried 3.x). When testing on >4.0.x it works as expected.

I have tried debugging and going through callback methods, but I can't figure out why this happens. Can it be a bug in older versions of Android, or is it because menus and such are handled differently? (shouldn't though since I'm using `ActionbarSherlock`).

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

**EDIT:**

I noticed that the problem occurs to the `fragments/tabs` that are not added first to the `ViewPager`, no matter what action item is in the menu. The first `tab`, i.e. the one that is active once the `Activity` starts, never has this problem.

Is it just me who is missing something, or is this how it's supposed to be?

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem? I think I have a similar one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It might help you

For spinner

```
 <com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner_id_name"
     style="@style/your_style_name"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="5dp"
     android:scrollbars="none" />
```

In style.xml you apply this

```
        <style name="your_style_name">
            <item name="android:dropDownWidth">fill_parent</item>
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background</item>
            <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/spinner_dropdown_background</item>
            <item name="android:divider">@color/gray_darkest</item>
            <item name="android:alignmentMode">alignBounds</item>
            <item name="android:dividerHeight">2dp</item>
            <item name="android:scrollbars">none</item>
            <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">false</item>
            <item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@android:color/transparent</item>
            <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@android:color/holo_dark</item>
            <item name="android:requiresFadingEdge">none</item>
        </style>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the problem still occurs. see my updated post

Comment: I think you have problem in backgorund image, slice it again. Then you should slightly adjust the background image of the spinner, It should not touch the edge of the screen

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by slicing the background image, but as i wrote in the update, the problem doesn't only involve Spinners but all menu items that are not in the active fragment when the activity starts

Comment: your spinner's and dropdown item's edges should not touch the left and right edge of the screen. Then you will get correct output

Comment: previously i got the same probs, I solved by adjusting left and right edge of the spinner and drop down item view

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. In my case the `Activity` was extending another one and the "parent" activity was returning `false` in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` function. This was causing wrong behaviour on Android 2.x, on Android 4 all was OK. When I changed the code to return `true` all is fixed. Another very strange thing I noticed was that the non-working `ActionItem` icons where darker then the good ones (in another `Activity`).